# Excel Drop down lists

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a drop down list of product names.  Each of these products has an assigned group of employees.  I would like to select the product name and then have the assigned employees names automatically populate in the next column.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want the assigned group of employees populate a **drop-down** in the next column?  If so, what you are after is dependent data validation.

It requires a bit of prep work to set up all the products and the employees. On a helper sheet you need to create a list of employees for each product and then assign each of these employee lists a range name that is identical to the product name in the drop-down.

[image]

This is the helper sheet. The three products are "apples", "bananas" and "carrots". They each have a list of employees. The highlighted list of employees in column A has the range name "Apples".

Here is a screenshot of the data entry sheet.

[image]

When you select "Apples" in column A, the drop-down in column B will show the employees for "Apples". If you select "Bananas", the drop-down will show the employees from the "Bananas" range in the helper sheet.

The drop-down in column B uses data validation with the Indirect() function with the value of column A as the argument. So the range that has the same name as the value in column A will be used to populate the drop-down.

[image]

That's the summary. For the complete tutorial take a look at [Debra Dalgleish's tutorial on the Contextures web site.](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)